# Product of Ideals in Ring that is not UFD

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

can someone tell me if I calculated the following products of Ideals correctly?

$I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5}),\ J=(3,1+\sqrt{-5}), K=(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

then

$I\cdot J=(1+\sqrt{-5})\\ I\cdot K=(1-\sqrt{-5})\\I^2=(2)\\J\cdot K=(3) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reference, this website is **NOT** for checking calculations. You should really learn how to use a calculator for that. I would like to direct you to [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) or [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).

```
sage: K.<r> = NumberField(x^2 + 5)
sage: Ok = K.ring_of_integers() 
sage: r*r
-5
sage: I = Ideal(2, 1 + r)
sage: J = Ideal(3, 1 + r)
sage: K = Ideal(3, 1 - r)
sage: I*J
Fractional ideal (r + 1)
sage: I*K
Fractional ideal (-r + 1)
sage: I*I
Fractional ideal (2)
sage: J*K
Fractional ideal (3)
sage:
```

So they are all correct.

Comment: No, it's semester break over here and I'm reading a book I'm interested in, so I was interested in whether I understood everything.
I didn't know about sage and I'm quite surprised about this. Maybe I will get a hand on it!

Comment: Less annoying than the students who post assignments, but I still don't think that asking essentially computational questions is relevant.

Comment: I'm sorry for sounding angrier in the answer. In my head, you were just a lazy person who couldn't be bothered checking multiplication. -- within  Algebraic Number Theory computation is very important, I think Sage will serve you well.

Comment: Which book are you reading btw?, also if you edit your question a bit, I can change my downvote, unless you're fine with me downvoting it.

Comment: Introduction to commutative algebra by Atiyah-Macdonald. I guess I will give sage a try if I have enough time. Thanks for introducing me to it:)

Comment: You may also enjoy Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox, Little and O'Shea. It's more computational and can give a better insight, especially at ground level. If you're more interested in the Algebraic Number Theory side, you may enjoy a book of the same name by Jarvis.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to know that for finitely generated ideals, for example $I = (a,b)$ and $J=(c,d)$, the ideal $IJ = (ac,ad,bc,bd)$ is the ideal generated by all products of generators. That said, you only need to check that you computed those products correctly.

For example, $$IJ=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1+\sqrt{-5}) = (6,2+2\sqrt{-5},3+3\sqrt{-5},-4+2\sqrt{-5}) \\= (2+2\sqrt{-5},3+3\sqrt{-5})=(1+\sqrt{-5}),$$ since $$3+3\sqrt{-5}-(2+2\sqrt{-5}) = 1+\sqrt{-5}.$$ The others are checked similarly.

Comment: But in your case it's $IJ=I$ and since $IJ\subset I\cap J\subset J$ it follows that $I\subset J$ which is not correct ($2\notin J$).

Comment: As user424862 notes, your computation of $IJ$ is not quite correct, since $(1+\sqrt{-5})^{2} = -4+2\sqrt{-5}$.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I know how to compute those products. My question was just about whether they're correct. So if one could verify that I'd be glad.

Comment: Have you tried learning how to use Sage? or Magma? It would be much faster and more convenient for checking calculations